# No errors prompted - cannot pull data from second table

Tags: php, mysql

2 tables, `users`  and `useradvert` (both have relation in sql working fine, just cannot pull data from second table `useradvert`). table `User` (Primary key-`id`) related to table `useradvert`(index key-`id`). below is extract.

//calling for record from table-users and table-useradvert, joined

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
   $userName = $_POST['username']; 
   $query = "SELECT users.id, users.name, users.username, users.telno, useradvert.id, useradvert.name2, useradvert.color2, useradvert.hobby2, useradvert.radiobtn, useradvert.kupon, useradvert.image, useradvert.image2 ". "FROM users 
LEFT JOIN useradvert ON useradvert.id = users.id"." WHERE username= ?";   
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
   $stmt->bind_param('s',$userName);
   $stmt->execute();
   $res = $stmt->get_result(); 
   $row = $res->fetch_array();
   $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
   $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
   $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
   $_SESSION['telno'] = $row['telno'];
   $_SESSION['name2'] = $row['name2'];
   $_SESSION['color2'] = $row['color2'];
   $_SESSION['hobby2'] = $row['hobby2'];
   $_SESSION['radiobtn'] = $row['radiobtn'];
   $_SESSION['kupon'] = $row['kupon'];
   $_SESSION['image'] = $row['image'];
   $_SESSION['image2'] = $row['image2'];    
}
?>
```

continue extract below...

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="apDiv3">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span class="TabbedPanelsContent">
  <?php
  //display record from table- users (parent table can display)
    echo $_SESSION['id']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['name']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['username']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['telno']."<br/>";
?>

<?php
//display records from table -useradvert (child table cannot display)

while($row = $res->fetch_array()){
"<br/>";
"<br/>";
"<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['id']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['name2']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['color2']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['hobby2']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['radiobtn']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['kupon']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['image']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['image2']."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Please help

Comment: Try like `echo $query; die;` and run your file and copy that query and run in your mysql server and let me know what it returns?

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing a `LEFT JOIN`? Do you expect some users to be in one table but not the other?

Comment: hi @vmachan. Yes.. there is a reason using left join. because,  in the parent table (users) there must always be a data. This is where the the users registration data stored. in the second table (useradvert), they have a choice to fill in their extra personal data to be shared later and to be stored. In this section (useradvert), they can have multiple rows  for 1 single id.

Comment: hi @Kausha Mehta.. God bless u. tq so much for the help. i forgot to mention above. I'm a totally newbie n have limited knowledge in PHP. for this single page, it took me 3 weeks above to develop. i'm very slow. :-(

Comment: @ml2 So what is the issue, have you run the printed query to mysql?

Comment: i dont know how to do it @Kausha Mehta...:-(

Comment: i really have limited knowledge. i apologise

Comment: It looks you are doing `$row = $res->fetch_array()` 2 times. Unless you have 2 or more rows, then the 2nd call will not return anything.

Comment: @ml2 `echo $query; die;`, write this line after your `$query` variable, then run the file as you run..... and process the same, and when you can see the query in your browser.... copy that query and goto mysql like `//localhost/phpmyadmin` and goto your DB and then goto SQL and paste query there and press go button and tell me what it returns....

Comment: i already run echo $query; die; in my page below the @query variable.it displays..SELECT users.id, users.name, users.username, users.telno, useradvert.id, useradvert.name2, useradvert.color2, useradvert.hobby2, useradvert.radiobtn, useradvert.kupon, useradvert.image, useradvert.image2 FROM users LEFT JOIN useradvert ON useradvert.id = users.id WHERE username= ? on the browser

Comment: I have not done it yet on the sql, im a bit afraid because i might mess up the entire DB.

Comment: run the query on your `phpmyadmin` and see what it results.

Comment: ill give it a try.. wait a moment

Comment: im not sure if im doing the the right thing. i just copy paste the echo $query; die in the query section in phpmyadmin and press go.. i got this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'echo $query' at line 1

Comment: sorry wrong section.. i run the query in the sql section instead of query section in phpmyadmin. now i paste the query in query section i got this "You have to choose at least one column to display"

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my codes above? Am I doing it wrongly?

Comment: Can you please tell us the foreign key column name in "useradvert" table and primary key column also for this table?

Comment: Hi @Mohit Aggarwal . the FK in table useradvert is id and the PK in table users is id...

Comment: its ok. btw i manage to solve the riddle after several hours of pain and headaches. btw tq all for your kind effort and help.

Comment: I accidently mixed the join queries with the first queries for login which cause a hazzard for me previously.

Answer (score 0):

answers below (i am sharing this so anyone who has the same problem in the world can refer this as a guidance.)

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){



    $userName = $_POST['username'];
    $query = "SELECT id, name, username, telno FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $userName);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result(); 
    $row = $res->fetch_array();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['telno'] = $row['telno'];



    $query = "SELECT useradvert.name2, useradvert.color2, useradvert.hobby2,useradvert.radiobtn, useradvert.kupon, useradvert.image, useradvert.image2 FROM users INNER JOIN useradvert ON users.id=useradvert.id ";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result(); 
    $row2 = $res->fetch_array();

  // $_SESSION['name'] = $row2['name'];
    $_SESSION['name2'] = $row2['name2'];
    $_SESSION['color2'] = $row2['color2'];
    $_SESSION['hobby2'] = $row2['hobby2'];
    $_SESSION['radiobtn'] = $row2['radiobtn'];
    $_SESSION['kupon'] = $row2['kupon'];
    $_SESSION['image'] = $row2['image'];
    $_SESSION['image2'] = $row2['image2'];

}
?>
```

extract below on same page..

```
  <?php
  //display record from table- users (parent table)
    echo $_SESSION['id']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['name']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['username']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['telno']."<br/>";
?>
```

extract below on same page..

```
 <?php
  //display record from table- useradveret -(child table)
  while($row = $res->fetch_array()){
   // echo $_SESSION['name']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['name2']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['color2']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['hobby2']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['radiobtn']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['kupon']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['image']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['image2']."<br/>";}

?>
```